# Content is nothing or is it

Tags: c#

it is such that I need to find out about my content is empty or not,

if it is empty it must just go down to detailed but if it is not empty, the tag it as is in if

```
if (long.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"]) != null)
{
    _subscriptionId = long.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"]);
}
else
{
    _subscriptionId = long.Parse(reader["abonnementsId"].ToString());
}
```

When I mouse over long in my if statement comes on and says:

**Resultatat of expression is always' true 'because the value of type' long 'is never equal to' null 'of type long?'**

Comment: There is not enough context, There are many things that require try/catch. parse always returns a long OR throws an exception, which explains your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check `HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"]` for `null` **before** parsing. If you do `long.Parse` then it will return a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) *(long)* which can't be null and hence the warning.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"] != null)
{
    _subscriptionId = long.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"]);
}
```

Comment: okay, I did not know, this is the first time I am working with c # / asp.net

Answer (score 1):

The message says what it means: the `long` type can not be ever a `null` if not when it is a [Nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.110).aspx).   In your case it would be probbably enough to

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"] != null)
{
   ....
}
```

First check for `null`, after execute a conversion to `long`, if required.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` value is never `null` and `long.Parse()` will never return null. You can use `long.TryParse()`:

```
long _subscriptionId;

if (long.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request["subscriptionid"],out _subscriptionId))
{
   ...
}
```